Escaping prisoner question
the question:
A prisoner is locked in a cell that has 3 doors.
The first door leads to the cell after 2 days of wandering.
The second door leads to a cell after 3 days of wandering.
The third door leads immediately to freedom.
- The prisoner chooses the first door with probability 0.5, the second door with 
probability 0.3 and the third door with probability .0.2

Calculate the span of the number of hours until he is free if the opening door is 
chosen at random but a previously chosen door will not be chosen again

my problem is with the part saying (#):"previously chosen door will not be chosen again"
without this part id know how to solve it, it would be basically:
E(X) = t
t = 0.5(2+t) + 0.3(3+t)
t = 9.5 -> in days so its 9.5 * 24 = 228Hrs
How do I approach this part(#) of the question?

That means the thing ends in at most three days, and the only things you have to look at are 1-2-3, 2-1-3, 1-3, 2-3, and 3.

I see, thank you

Assuming that the prisoner's first choice is the first door, then you have that for his 2nd choice, he must choose either door 2 (relative probability = 0.3) or door 3 (relative probability = 0.2).  Using conditional probability what then is the probability that the prisoner's next choice will be door 2 rather than door 3?

Assume that the likelihood of choosing a specific door remains proportional when a door is eliminated. For example, if door 1 is chosen first, the likelihood after the prisoner returns is 60% door 2 and 40% door 3. I did this inline below but can explain further if needed.
Your treatment of door 3 in the expectation was correct, but we still have to handle each "path" and the elimination of choices. I used subscripts to denote which doors have not yet been explored, so we are in search of $\mathbb{E}_{123}(t)$. We can enumerate each scenario (I used days here).
$$
\mathbb{E}_{123}(t) = p_1\cdot(\mathbb{E}_{23}(t) + 2) + p_2\cdot(\mathbb{E}_{13}(t)+3) + p_3\cdot(0)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}_{23}(t) = p_2\cdot(3) + p_3\cdot(0)=3\cdot0.3\div0.5 =1.8
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}_{13}(t) = p_1\cdot(2) + p_3\cdot(0)=2\cdot0.5\div0.7=\frac{10}{7}
$$
Putting it all together,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{123}(t) = 0.5\cdot(1.8 + 2) + 0.3\cdot(\frac{10}{7}+3)\approx3.23 days
$$
Realizing now the question asked for span - I did expectation above.
The "span" (which I guess would mean range of possible values?) is from no time (picking door 3, probability 0.2) to the max of 5 days. The probability of this max also needs my first assumption, but is either door 1 then door 2 (0.5 then 0.6) or door 2 then door 1(0.3 then 10/7), about 73% chance total.
